# WiFi often takes a long time to connect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

Ever since I have had my Macbook Pro (2015), it always seems to have this issue where the WiFi can (and does often) take a long time to connect to a router. Just today, it took 8 minutes to connect to my home router. Before trying to connect, I decided to backup and move the file wifi.log within the /var/log/ folder and then as soon as it connected I made a copy of the file. By looking through the file I cannot work out what the issue may be. Below is the contents of the log file:

```
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.367 <kernel> en0: Terminating supplicant.
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.367 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for b0:39:56:8b:ad:7b
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.367 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 5 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.367 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress d0:a6:37:e9:df:81
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.367 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 <kernel> Unexpected payload found for message 9, dataLen 0
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 <kernel> en0: Received EAPOL packet (length = 113)
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: 0 extra bytes present in EAPOL frame.
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: Received message 1 of 4
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 <kernel> FULL RSN IE FOUND:
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 [00000000] 30 14 01 00 00 0F AC 04 01 00 00 0F AC 04 01 00 00 0F AC 02 00 00 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 <kernel> storeFullRSNIE: getAP_IE_LIST returned 0
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 <kernel> PMK:
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.534 [00000000] 87 6B 39 88 D2 DE 1E EE C1 D1 FC 06 08 56 0C C1 91 6A DF 33 EF 88 16 F8 8F 50 15 EF 68 0C 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 [0000001E] 89 70 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 <kernel> TPTK:
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 [00000000] EA 1E C9 2A A4 0C 58 46 80 D7 FE E3 4C DB A7 44 11 7A 72 B7 A6 CA 36 8E 21 7C A7 2C 08 3E 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 [0000001E] 62 3A D9 65 98 F8 3C DC E6 18 31 0C 68 AA 55 4C 09 E1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 [0000003C] 00 00 00 00 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 <kernel> KEY MIC:
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 [00000000] 9C F7 31 96 61 80 0A 02 A4 52 D1 58 D2 DB D3 A1 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.535 <kernel> process1of4: sending replyPacket 135 bytes
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> en0: Received EAPOL packet (length = 169)
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: 0 extra bytes present in EAPOL frame.
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: decrypting key data
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> inputEAPOLFrame: Received message 3 of 4
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> process3of4: Performing IE check.
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> process3of4: sending replyPacket ( len = 113 ).
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> process3of4: received pairwise GTK
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.539 <kernel> ptkThread: Sleeping!
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.540 <kernel> ptkThread: Installing PTK!
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.540 <kernel> PTK:
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.540 [00000000] D9 65 98 F8 3C DC E6 18 31 0C 68 AA 55 4C 09 E1 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.541 <kernel> ptkThread: Installing GTK!
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.541 <kernel> installGTK: setting cipher key (flags = 0x0)
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.541 <kernel> GTK-RSC:
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.541 [00000000] 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.541 <kernel> GTK:
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.541 [00000000] 5B 61 1D 29 9D 6F 02 EE DF 44 01 32 7D BF 07 1A 
Mon Mar  5 21:05:48.541 <kernel> installGTK: GTK installed
Mon Mar  5 21:13:31.212 <airportd[165]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
Mon Mar  5 21:13:31.228 <airportd[165]> _processIPv4Changes: ARP/NDP offloads disabled, not programming the offload
```

If the above file does not help identify the issue, what else can I do to debug this problem? Note that I do not have this problem on any of my other devices for other operating systems - windows, ubuntu, iOS, Android.

Comment: This log makes it look like Wi-Fi got connected and fully authenticated within 1 second. It could be that DHCP is what’s taking too long, not Wi-Fi.

Comment: Spiff is probably correct. What happens when you statically set your local IP on the adapter? Does it then connect in a reasonable time?